# SuperFastHash returns different hashes for equal strings, but only if determined by different function calls

Tags: c, hashtable, hash-function

So, my SFH function:

```
/*  
 * Hash function (found at: 'http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/hash.html')  
 */ 
int32_t SuperFastHash(const char * data, int len)  {
    uint32_t hash = len, tmp;
    int rem;

    if (len <= 0 || data == NULL) return 0;

    rem = len & 3;
    len >>= 2;

    /* Main loop */
    for (;len > 0; len--) {
        hash  += get16bits (data);
        tmp    = (get16bits (data+2) << 11) ^ hash;
        hash   = (hash << 16) ^ tmp;
        data  += 2*sizeof (uint16_t);
        hash  += hash >> 11;
    }

    /* Handle end cases */
    switch (rem) {
        case 3: hash += get16bits (data);
                hash ^= hash << 16;
                hash ^= ((signed char)data[sizeof (uint16_t)]) << 18;
                hash += hash >> 11;
                break;
        case 2: hash += get16bits (data);
                hash ^= hash << 11;
                hash += hash >> 17;
                break;
        case 1: hash += (signed char)*data;
                hash ^= hash << 10;
                hash += hash >> 1;
    }

    /* Force "avalanching" of final 127 bits */
    hash ^= hash << 3;
    hash += hash >> 5;
    hash ^= hash << 4;
    hash += hash >> 17;
    hash ^= hash << 25;
    hash += hash >> 6;

    // Limits hashes to be within the hash table    
    return hash % HT_LENGTH; 
}
```

It looks like it's working fine, (and it should since everything but the last line is untouched by me).

Here is the function where I load my dictionary into the hash table which also seems to be working dandy.

```
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
    // declares file pointer
    FILE* dictptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    // declare temp index
    uint32_t index = 0;

    // read words, one by one
    while(true)
    {

        // malloc node
        node* new_node = malloc(node_size);

        // insert word into node, if fscanf couldn't scan word; we're done
        if (fscanf(dictptr, "%s", new_node->word) != 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        // hash word - HASH FUNCTION CALL -
        index = SuperFastHash(&new_node->word[0], sizeof(new_node->word));

        // check if head node has been assigned with value
        if (!strcmp(hashtable[index].word,""))
        {
            // declare hashtable[index] to new_node
            hashtable[index] = *new_node;

            //increment size
            hashtablesize++;
        }

        else
        {
            // if node is initialized, insert after head 
            new_node->next = hashtable[index].next;
            hashtable[index].next = new_node;

            //increment size
            hashtablesize++;
        }
    } 
}
```

And finally, my check function which checks a word against the hashtable.

```
bool check(const char* keyword)
{

    // gets index from SFH
    uint32_t index = SuperFastHash(keyword, sizeof(keyword));

    // declares head pointer to the pointer of the index'd element of hashtable
    node* head = &hashtable[index];

    // if word of head is equal to keyword, return true 
    // else continue down chain till head is null or key is found
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if (!strcmp(head->word, keyword))
        {
            return true;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

NOTE: When using a different hash function everything works fine so I suspect the problem to reside with the len argument or in the actual SFH function.

I've checked with lldb that the index returned for, say, "cat" is not equal to the index in which "cat" resides in the hash table. That is, the index as returned by the function call in load.

Comment: `sizeof(keyword)` is not correct. That just gives you the size of a pointer to `char`. Which is always 4 or 8 depending on whether your system is 32 or 64 bit. Should be `strlen(keyword)` or `strlen(keyword) + 1` (depending on whether the hash function expects the NUL terminator - I didn't look closely at that). Fix that and you'll probably get the right result.

Comment: Oh my christ, thank you so much, should've seen that! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things ...

1. As a commenter mentioned, using `sizeof()` will not give you the correct string length.  For example, change

   ```
   index = SuperFastHash(&new_node->word[0], sizeof(new_node->word));
   ```

   to

   ```
   index = SuperFastHash(&new_node->word[0], strlen(new_node->word));
   ```
2. You are failing to call `fclose()` after reading your dictionary file.  If `fopen()` succeeds, you should call `fclose()`.
3. The following code looks a little suspicious:

   ```
   // check if head node has been assigned with value
   if (!strcmp(hashtable[index].word,""))
   {
       // declare hashtable[index] to new_node
       hashtable[index] = *new_node;

       //increment size
       hashtablesize++;
   }
   ```

If the hash table is fully initialized at the start, do you need to increment `hashtablesize`?  If the hash table is not fully initialized, then calling `strcmp()` on entries that are not yet initialized is potential trouble.  You didn't show the declaration or initialization code, so it's not 100% clear whether this is actually a problem, but may be something to double check.

Comment: Thank you, perfect! Yeah, `fclose()` resides in the `unload()` function that I didn't include in the post! 

Well `hashtablesize` is really just poorly named as it's more of a `wordsloaded` variable! The hashtable is initialized from the start.

Comment: The return value from `fopen()` is stored in a local variable, so not sure how a separate unload function would have access to that -- that's why I mentioned it.  Or, perhaps the code that is posted is different than your actual code?